# PHP: Mongo client not found

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, mongodb

I've installed XAMPP on my MacBook. PHP and MySQL are working fine, so I followed it up with mongo. I did the following:

- brew install mongo (success)
- brew install autoconf (success)
- sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo (success)

So far so good. I added the complete mongo.so path to the very end of `/etc/php.ini like so:

> [mongo]
>   extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mongo.so

**The Problem:**

Typing in `php --version`, however, returns the following:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20121212
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
>   These options need to match  in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15)

**What I Tried:**

I managed to get rid of that error above (notice: get rid), by updating OS X's PHP via the following: `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5`

I then added the following lines to .bash_profile: `export PATH=~/bin:/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`

`php -m` now lists mongo as one of the modules, and it no longer produces the above error.

*However, phpinfo() does NOT have mongo, and running my webpage using mongo client gives me the following error:*

> FatalErrorException   Class 'MongoClient' not found

So, I repeated the following: `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/pecl install mongo`

And now it's telling me that my mongo is up to date:

pecl/mongo is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.5.5

**Additional info:**

- PHP version: PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Jun 28 2014 10:29:43)
- Mongo version: MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
- Mongo client: 1.5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you type `php --version` or `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php --version`? And to which php.ini did you add that line? To `/etc/php.ini` or to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini`?

The first path always references OS-X default PHP (which is PHP5.4), the later references XAMPPs PHP (which is PHP5.5 and has a different API then PHP5.4).

So I assume that you compiled the module for PHP5.5 (XAMPP) and have added it to PHP5.4 (OS-X). That can't work at all! You'l have to add the mongo so-Path to the end of the correct php.ini-file which in your case is the one for XAMPP which (if I recall corerctly) is located at `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php.ini`

Comment: I found it in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/`. That did it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the info. I did out of my head and wasn't sure about lib or etc.... I've edited the answer to show the correct path!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this for days. It worked out being the `XAMPP\etc\php.ini`. I added `/usr/local/php5-5.6.25-20160831-101628/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/mongo.so` and it worked fine. To find where the `mongo.so` files are in Terminal enter `locate mongo.so`